# is paleohacks.com a stack exchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

http://paleohacks.com/

Is this a StackExchange site? It looks and seems to function the exact same, but seems to have its own user system, and doesn't contain links to all of the other SE sites at the bottom like all the ones I've seen do.

If this is not an "official" SE site is it acceptable for third party sites to "copy" the look & feel of SE to this extent or is this site in violation of something?

Comment: Looks like one of the old stackexchange sites where you had to pay a monthly fee but didn't need to pass area51. Some of these sites are still around. Check the meta generator tag.

Comment: Nice; I thought I knew of all of the remaining active 1.0 sites, but I hadn't seen this one.

Comment: If you feed your site a proper paleo diet, it *naturally* looks like that.

Comment: @Shog9 lolol.  (Upvote did not express that well enough.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It <strike>is</strike> was an old SE 1.0 site. The header states:

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

It has since moved onto a different platform and no longer uses the Stack Exchange software.

Comment: Ouch. It's not even 1.0!

Comment: Is there a list of beta sites anywhere?

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I'm pretty sure this and Math Overflow are the last surviving ones, though don't quote me on that.

Comment: @AnnaLear Math Overflow is now integrated, now it's time to integrate paleo :-)

Comment: It has moved away from SE now - we just redirect the old domain to them. No idea what platform they chose.

Comment: @Oded: It has a AnswerHub.com logo and link at the bottom of the homepage. :-) I think we can take that as a big hint.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I didn't click through... It was that important to me ;)